# Macbook screen freezes when I move my external mouse

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse, performance

I recently updated to macOS Big Sur, and I wanted to use my external mouse for work and gaming. I plugged in my mouse using a USB dongle, but every time I moved the mouse, the screen would freeze. In the games that I was playing, if I didn't move my mouse, I was getting around 80 FPS but as soon as I started moving my mouse, my frames would drop significantly, to around 15 FPS,  but they would improve as soon as I stopped moving my mouse. This issue doesn't happen at all when I use the trackpad. Is there any fix for this issue?

Laptop Specs:
MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015)
1.1 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core M
8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Intel HD Graphics 5300 1536 MB

Comment: *I plugged in my mouse using a USB dongle,*  What type of dongle?  Is it for the mouse itself (like Logitech) or some 3rd party brand?

Comment: It's a USB-C hub that I attach to my MacBook so I can plug in USB-A devices. I am using a Razer Deathadder wired mouse, and I plug the mouse USB into my USB hub.

Comment: I've seen it before....  Discount hubs can cause all sorts of issues.  Get a [proper USB-C hub](https://amzn.to/36dRyqs) that *only* gives you more USB Ports not a multi function hub with ports, video, Ethernet, etc.  Anker, Plugable and StarTech are all go-to brands IMO.  Yes, they cost more but they pay for themselves with the issues you don't have to deal with

Comment: I only recently started having this issue. I have used my mouse with this USB-C hub before and it worked perfectly fine. I will get a better USB hub and let you know though.

Comment: I got the USB hub from Anker that you had linked but I am still having the same issue. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I have been experiencing a similar problem with my Logitech G Pro Wireless mouse plugged into an Anker hub. I believe I have resolved my issue by changing the mouse's polling rate from 1000 to 250 in the G Hub software for the mouse. You may try changing the polling rate, if your mouse supports it, and see if that helps with your issue.